# Jquery / Colorbox - Stopped working

Tags: jquery, css

Have an image gallery with color box jquery plugin. Was working at first - then stopped. Have tried everything I can think of, so must be simply missing something.

Link:

http://loverich-lopez.com/photos.php

links are grouped using 'a[rel="engage"]' tag. I can alert a query on them so I know they are being selected.

File structure has photos.php in main directory, then the scripts and css files in a 'js' and 'css' folder, respectively. Edited the colorbox.css so it could find the locations of its gif's in my images folder.

All necessary files - colorbox.css, jquery, personal script, and colorbox script are all linked (can view source and click on them).

tried setting the iframe's = true (no idea what it does, but didn't help - changed it back).

Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you change the version of jquery being used. Check whether the Jquery version and the colorboc plugin version are comp[atible. I faced the same issue when I moved from 1.4.2 to 1.5.1. Also update the Juqery-UI plugin if you moved up the version.

Comment: Actually tried using 1.5.1 in the sample files just to make sure it worked first - no problem's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the order in your html; you have put the plugin before jquery itself and that results in an error in the plugin (in firebug) that jQuery is not defined.

Just put jquery first and then the plugin and the problem should be solved.

Comment: Yup. Oddly I moved it like that on purpose when it wasn't working - must have fixed some other problem post move. Thanks :)